# Insert object to specific position in jsonarray

Tags: java, arrays, json

I want to add an object to a specific position in JSonArray.
My Current JsonArray look like this

```
{
    "imgs": [
        "String1",
        "String2",
        "String3",
        "String4"
    ]
}
```

I need to insert one more item in jsonarray at 1st position like this-

```
jsonArray.put(1,"String5")
```

this is replacing item at first position
But I need below result

```
{
    "imgs": [
        "String1",
        "String5",
        "String2",
        "String3",
        "String4"
    ]
}
```

Please suggest

Comment: Did one of the answers solve your problem? If yes, then please accept that answer.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Seem too old but you can do like this:

```
public void addToPos(int pos, JSONObject jsonObj, JSONArray jsonArr){
   for (int i = jsonArr.length(); i > pos; i--){
      jsonArr.put(i, jsonArr.get(i-1));
   }
   jsonArr.put(pos, jsonObj);
}
```

Comment: saved a lot of headache. +1

Comment: work for me when data populate from server

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
String myString = jsonArray.getString(1);
jsonArray.put(1,"String5");
jsonArray.put(myString);
```

Comment: This will add previous 1st position to last position . but If want previous 1st position to shift on 2nd position and previous 3rd to 4th and so on.... Is there any optimised solution expect full iteration ?

Comment: @XYZ with the methods provided in `JSONArray` class, i think full iteration is the only way.

Answer (score 4):

Android `JSONArray` is not meant as a general-purpose data structure, but to (de)serialize data to and from JSON. Therefore, you should do all add/remove/mutate operations on a `java.util.List` or something and only if you want to send it over the wire convert to a `JSONArray`.

Java EE 7 also has a `JsonArray` class, in their API description they make abundantly clear that they want to prevent people from using it as a replacement for a `java.util.list`: `JsonArray instances are list objects that provide read-only access to the values in the JSON array. Any attempt to modify the list, whether directly or using its collection views, results in an UnsupportedOperationException.`

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3741653/2535335)

Answer (score 1):

call this function like this

String changed_json_string= changeJson(jsonString,2,"hai")

```
  public String changeJson(String json,int index,String add_string){

            try {
                JSONObject job=new JSONObject(json);
                JSONArray jsonArray=job.getJSONArray("imgs");

                ArrayList<String> arrayList=new ArrayList<>();
                for (int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++){
                    String abc= (String) jsonArray.get(i);
                    arrayList.add(abc);


                 }


                arrayList.add(index,add_string);

                JSONObject a=new JSONObject();
                JSONArray jar=new JSONArray();


                for (String str:
                arrayList) {
                    jar.put(str);

                }
                a.put("imgs",jar);

               return a.toString();






            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();

            }

            return "";
        }
```

output

```
{"imgs":["String1","String2","hai","String3","String4"]}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use array shifting logic or create copy of new json array with newly inserted element and insert into original json ojbect.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `JsonArrayBuilder` object.

```
private JsonArray insertAt(int index, String value, JsonArray origArray) {

    JsonArrayBuilder resultBuilder = Json.createBuilderFactory(null).createArrayBuilder();

    // Insert elements before the position
    for (JsonValue elemValue : origArray.subList(0, index)) {
        resultBuilder.add(elemValue);
    }

    // Insert your element
    resultBuilder.add(value);

    // Insert the rest of elements.
    for (JsonValue elemValue : origArray.subList(index, origArray.size())) {
        resultBuilder.add(elemValue);
    }

    return resultBuilder.build();
}
```

Note that the arguments check is not done here. Also instead of having a string as value to insert you can have a JsonValue to be more generic.

Answer (score 0):

Copy and paste solution:

```
import org.json.JSONArray;
import java.util.ArrayList;
...
public void insertAt(int index, Object value, JSONArray jsonArray) {
        ArrayList<Object> arrayList = new ArrayList<Object>(jsonArray.toList());
        arrayList.add(index, value);
        //Empty deprecated jsonArray
        jsonArray.clear();
        //Refill cleared jsonArray in the correct order including the new value at the correct position
        for(int k = 0; k < arrayList.size(); ++k)
            jsonArray.put(arrayList.get(k));
    }
```

Use this if you want to apply it in an Android App (To understand why read the following post: [changing or upgrading built-in org.json libraries, is possible and a good idea?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20389105/changing-or-upgrading-built-in-org-json-libraries-is-possible-and-a-good-idea)):

```
public static void insertAt(int index, Object value, JSONArray jsonArray) {
    try {
        JSONArray copyOfJsonArray = new JSONArray(jsonArray.toString());
        int newLength = jsonArray.length()+1;
        for( int i = index; i < newLength; ++i) {
            if(i == index)
                jsonArray.put(i, value);
            else
                jsonArray.put(i, copyOfJsonArray.get(i-1));
        }
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```